# Execute immediate can't bind result into a variable

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, execute-immediate

Without into tables_found procedure will run but i need to check if this table exist in my database .

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE dropdb(tables_found out number) IS
    BEGIN                                  
        execute immediate 'SELECT COUNT(*) into tables_found FROM user_tables where table_name=''USERS''';
    if (tables_found = 1) then 
        execute immediate ' drop table users';
    END IF;
END dropdb;
```

ERROR LOG :

> ora-00905 missing keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be this

```
Execute immediate 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_tables where table_name=''USERS'''  into tables_found;
```

or even better:

```
Execute immediate 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_tables where table_name=:name'  into tables_found using 'USERS';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
execute immediate 'SELECT COUNT(*) into :x FROM user_tables
where table_name=''USERS''' 
USING OUT tables_found ;
```

If the above will not work, try this:

```
   execute immediate 'DECLARE x NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) into x
   FROM user_tables
    where table_name=''USERS'';
    :tables := x END' 
    USING OUT tables_found ;
```